# Custom JSON Structural Mapping between different POJO classes using java

Tags: java, json

Please help me with below scenario. I will be getting some data from the database which will be in the below JSON structure.
JSON Strcture obtained after getting data from database:

```
{
            "employeeDetails":[
                {
                    "name":"ABC",
                    "age":"20",
                    "address":{
                        "street":"NC Street",
                        "area":"chn",
                        "country":"india"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name":"DEF",
                    "age":"25",
                    "address":{
                        "street":"BC Street",
                        "area":"njk",
                        "country":"india"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Based on the different channels, i have to customize the above JSON.
Custom Mapping for Channel 1:

```
{
            "emplDetails":[
                {
                    "emplName":"ABC",
                    "emplAge":"20",
                },
                {
                    "emplName":"DEF",
                    "emplAge":"25",
                }
            ],
            "emplAddress":[
                {
                    "emplstreet":"NC Street",
                    "emplarea":"chn",
                    "emplcountry":"india"
                },
                {
                    "emplstreet":"BC Street",
                    "emplarea":"njk",
                    "emplcountry":"india"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Custom Mapping for Channel 2:

```
{
            "emplDetails":[
                {
                    "emplName":"ABC",
                    "emplAge":"20",
                    "emplAddress":[
                        {
                            "emplstreet":"NC Street",
                            "emplarea":"chn",
                            "emplcountry":"india"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "emplName":"DEF",
                    "emplAge":"25",
                    "emplAddress":[
                        {
                            "emplstreet":"NC Street",
                            "emplarea":"chn",
                            "emplcountry":"india"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

I will be having different POJO classes based upon the channels. Is there a way to copy data from one pojo to another pojo which is having a different structure? How to implement this case in java?

Comment: create a dummy pojo for all these values and put all of above in that POJO after that from this dummy POJO values assign tham according to your channel POJO.

Comment: Is there a way to copy data from one pojo to another pojo which is having a different structure?

Comment: POJO having different structure means different data types. Now think is it possible ?